# Limiting http request in Nginx

Tags: http, nginx, limit, except

Completly new Noob with it comes to Nginx configs.  I'm trying to limit http requests based on IP:  Here's what I have so far:  I need to allow all GETs, however I need to limit PUT DELETE and POST to specific IP Ranges

```
location / {
            index app.php index.php index.html;
            try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
            limit_except GET {
                    allow all;
            }
            limit_except PUT DELETE POST {
                    allow <IP SUBNET 1>;
                    allow <IP SUBNET 2>;
                    deny all;
            }
```

Any idea what I'm getting wrong?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

The following will reject every method except `GET` and `HEAD`. If the client is from specified ip ranges, it will have access to other methods.

```
location / {
            index app.php index.php index.html;
            try_files $uri @rewriteapp;

            limit_except GET {
                    allow <IP SUBNET 1>;
                    allow <IP SUBNET 2>;
                    deny all;
            }
```

Comment: How to redirected the disallowed methods to another `proxy_pass`?

Comment: @W.M. You can redirect using if verb, `if ($request_method = POST ) {
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
  }`

Comment: For clarity, as I've just had the same problem, this limits EVERYTHING BUT GET. i.e. <ip subnet 1> will be allowed on POST, PUT, etc, but nothing else will. Everything will be allowed GET requests.